# How to use dynamic routes in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and Nextjs and i am working on dynamic routes,In other words i have list of blogs and now i want to display blog details for this i created folder name "blogs" and put file name "[slug.js"] inside this but unable to redirect to that url, Here is my current code in Allblog.tsx

```
 <Link href={`/blog/${todoList.id}`}>Edit</Link>
```

And here is my code inside "blog/[slug.js]"

```
    import Axios from "axios";
    import  {useRouter}  from "next/router";
    import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
    
    //import LatestBlogs from "../../components/LatestBlogs/LatestBlogs";
    import Link from 'next/link'
    import { useEffect, useState  } from 'react'
    import Sidebar from '../../components/Sidebar'
    
    const slug = ({ posts }) => {
      return(
          <div>
               <h2> Hello World </h2>
          </div>
        );
    
    };
    
    export default slug;
    
    
   export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
 const { data } = await Axios.get(`https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/getblogbyuserid/${params.slug}`);
  const post = data;
  return {
    
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/blogs");
  const posts = data.slice(0, 10);
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({ params: { slug: post.id.toString() } }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};
```

Comment: The question you ask in the title and the answer you're actually looking for are very different.  You're conflating react with next

Comment: file name should be blog/[slug].js

Answer (score 0):

file name should be blog/[slug].js

Comment: file name is correct , by mistake i wrote wrong file name

Comment: can you share a screenshot what do you see when you visit /blog/random